# HTML Area tag, showing text and/or graphic

Tags: html

I want to display text and/or a graphic on another graphic.

By using the following sample, I display a graphic, and can then "sensitize" parts of it using `AREA`:

```
<img src ="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap ="#planetmap" />

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus" />
</map>
```

How would I be able to display text and/or a graphic in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using HTML5 CANVAS. Area maps do not support this.

Here is a starter tutotial: http://blog.reybango.com/2010/07/01/canvas-baby-steps-an-introduction-to-the-html-5-canvas-element/